# Is there any tools that records the desktop actions and give a json file?

Tags: javascript, video

I am looking for something like selenium IDE which will work on windows desktop . So that i can record the user actions performed and export it to a json file.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question and specify one or more operating systems, and whether you are looking for recommendations for gratis or commercial software. Thanks!

Comment: I can hive you recommendations - but not saving to JSON ... just curious, why would you want to do that?